# mongoose virtual property not working in findById property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a `serviceSchema` shown below:

```js
const serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    tags: [
      {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    ],
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      get: (rawImage) => {
        return `${config.base_url}/uploads/${rawImage}`;
      },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: { getters: true, virtuals: true },
  }
);
```

I have defined a virtual like so:

```js
serviceSchema.virtual("avg_satis").get(function () {
  Session.find({ service: this._id, status: "conf" }, "satisfaction")
    .lean()
    .then((sessions) => {
      let sum = 0;
      sessions.forEach((session) => {
        sum += session.satisfaction;
      });
      console.log(sum / sessions.length);
      return sum / sessions.length;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

When I perform a query like so:

```js
      const service = await Service.findById(req.params.service_id).populate(
        "user",
        "_id name pp"
      );
      console.log(service.avg_satisf);
```

The virtual is undefined.

I also tried converting the virtual like this (without promises):

```js
serviceSchema.virtual("avg_satis").get(function () {
  Session.find({ service: this._id, status: "conf" }, "satisfaction")
    .lean()
    .exec((err, sessions) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      let sum = 0;
      sessions.forEach((session) => {
        sum += session.satisfaction;
      });
      console.log(sum / sessions.length);
      return sum / sessions.length;
    });
});
```

Comment: `virtual` not allow async function.

Comment: @hoangdv how would I fix that?

Comment: Add session schema to question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

virtual field is not real exist in database. It is a kind of shorthand, so you can’t query it.
What you want is call `populate`, please read doc and use it.

If you really want to get a promise in virtual

```js
serviceSchema.virtual("avg_satis").get(function () {
  // return promise to caller
  return Session.find({ service: this._id, status: "conf" }, "satisfaction")
    .lean()
    .then((sessions) => {
      let sum = 0;
      sessions.forEach((session) => {
        sum += session.satisfaction;
      });
      console.log(sum / sessions.length);
      return sum / sessions.length;
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});


// outside
await service.avg
```

There have another way in docs, such like static or method

----update

it's already in mongoose docs

```js
  // define a schema
  const animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

  // assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
  animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function(cb) {
    return mongoose.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
  };
```

so

```js
  // define a schema
  serviceSchema.methods.caleAvg = async function() {
    return Session.find({ service: this._id, status: "conf" }, "satisfaction")
    .lean()
    .then((sessions) => {
      let sum = 0;
      sessions.forEach((session) => {
        sum += session.satisfaction;
      });
      console.log(sum / sessions.length);
      return sum / sessions.length;
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

// outside caller
const avg = await service.caleAvg()
```

if you want to do it and append into its response in mongooDB, you need to study their `aggregate` pipeline.

Comment: Can you elaborate more

Comment: no, I mean update your question with more details about schema

Comment: and you return nothing in virtual getter, what are you really want to do?

Comment: I do return soemthing: ```return sum / sessions.length;```

Comment: But it is in a promise, `return Sesstion....` in getter

Comment: Is there a problem with it being in a promise? Should I use the callback version instead?

Comment: And await it, you will get the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227828/discussion-between--and-svoruganti).

Comment: can u specify the other static method